# Docker Node.JS cannot reach website

Tags: node.js, docker

I cannot load my Node.JS hosted website that is hosted out of a Docker container. Here are the steps I ran:

```
docker build -t website-server .
docker run -d -p 80:8080 website-server
docker ps -a
docker logs <ID>
```

Logs showed the server running on port 8080 fine, the console.log text was printed.

Important part of my app.js file:

```
http.createServer().listen(8080, (req, res) => {
    console.log("Started server");
});
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.4.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Everything works fine, but when I go to visit the website through the usual domain (or my VM's IP or my container's IP) it doesn't load. I'm guessing I'm overlooking a key step in the setup process or making a mistake. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you have done: that part should work.... I would look next at firewalls, starting with the network firewall by answering the questions 'where is the vm hosted?', 'is there a firewall on the network?' and 'what are the settings?'

If access is open there, look closer-in: iptables, or other firewall on the vm itself.